# input type="time" not working properly in windows 10 app

Tags: html, cordova, windows-10

I have a problem in my cross-platform app built using Cordova.
I am using the following

`<input type="time" placeholder="From time" ng-model="data.time">`

and it works like a charm for all platforms EXCEPT windows 10.
I get this timepicker where the only option I've got is to pick AM times (see image below)

[image: time picker]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please Show me your code

Comment: @HassanALi He did show it. It's the `input` element.

Comment: You are Right But i want to see that how is using it in real functioning .

Comment: Aren't the hours above (eg 11) PM times?

Comment: @HassanALi What more do you want to see?

Comment: @torazaburo Nope, they are AM too

Comment: @torazaburo Okey, I was wrong about that, they are PM. The control still show them as AM, but the resulting time is PM.

Comment: I want to see that how you implemented this . Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want